# Design patterns for non-modal (in-game) dialogues/cutscenes in a game engine

Tags: architecture, design-patterns, dialogue-tree

I want to create a scripted dialogues/sequences between NPCs and/or PC during the game.

I have a [DSL](https://martinfowler.com/dsl.html) to configure a PC's dialogue with one NPC, inspired by [Inkle](https://www.inklestudios.com/ink/) and [Twine](https://twinery.org/cookbook/terms/terms_storyformats.html).

Now, I need a dialogue between 2+ NPCs, where the PC can also participate.

Question: the dialogue object of PC-to-NPC dialogue is owned by that NPC, can receive all necessary events that drive the scripted dialogue/scene. But who should own a dialogue between multiple NPCs? This somebody should receive and handle events related to all the participants, check if the NPCs are still friendly and alive, and a few other things that wouldn't be a problem if it was a single NPC.

How is it done in the well-designed engines? I know you can attach a script object to a game entity in Unity, for example. Does the script get attached to location itself, or be standalone? How does this fit into event distribution mechanism?

I don't want to replace NPCs with a scripted sequence, I want them to maintain their normal properties during the scene.

Comment: Are you using a specific engine?

Comment: What does DSL stand for?

Comment: No, it’s my own dialogue engine. DSL stands for “Domain-specific language”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In game development, there is never just one solution to any given problem.

But one solution could be to create each active dialog as a separate, independent, invisible entity which references all participants of the conversation.

That entity would then be responsible to check if the conditions for starting the scene are met (the player entered the trigger area, both NPCs are alive and within certain areas, both NPCs are in a state which allows them to start a conversation, neither is involved in a different conversation right now, etc.). It would then keep checking the state of the characters involved in the scene to make sure the conditions for continuing the scene are still met. The entity would also decide when to show the next line of the conversation and be responsible for displaying it.

Comment: Let it be an invisible scripted object on the scene (while I agree that there is always more than one architectural solution).

Answer (score 1):

There are much smarter people here than me, but I'll pitch in with my $.02.

You asked about how others would approach this problem building a game in an engine like Unity. While I have not built a game with multiple NPCs talking to the player at once, I have built games where players can interact and converse with individual NPCs, and I think my approach to the former would be similar.

First of all, I usually start out with a basic class structure where all or at least most of the games' 'entities' derive from a pair of abstract base classes which I usually call `Item` and `ItemRuntime`.

[image: UML class diagram -- abstract Item and ItemRunTime]

`Item` derives from the Unity class `ScriptableObject` and defines the immutable data for that entity. `ItemRuntime` doesn't derive from anything, and will hold runtime data for each generated item instance as well as a few methods that would be awkward to keep in the immutable.

Everything else descends from these two base classes in a cascading manner. For instance, `Vehicle`, `Character` and `Loot` might be the base classes for things you can move around in, the various kinds of NPCs you find in the game, and the stuff you collect, respectively. More specific types can then derive from these. One such type might be a "Sentient NPC," an interactable character that can converse. The class definition would include a list of all the Items that character knows about (here shown as Awareness), as well as a list in the runtime that keeps track of what that character has already told the player about. Going backwards, each item type could define certain ways in which a character could speak about it, for instance, Loot might be "precious" or "rare," a vehicle might be "fast" or "rugged," a character might be "wise" or "combative" etc.

[[image: UML with classes derived from Item & ItemRuntime]

A master controller would keep track of what the player knows about so that conversations with NPCs have context, while the scripts for the SentientNPCs regarding the various items they are aware of would be defined within the SentientNPC class.